# Mongoose aggregation $lookup returns empty array in 'as' field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say we have two collections: `Order` and `Seller` for an Ebay like business where customers can order items from individual sellers.

Each `Order` contains a `seller` field which lists the ID of the shop owner.

```js
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Seller' },
  item: { type: String },
});

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
```

When I try to use $lookup

```js
  const aggregateOrdersWithSellerInfo = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Seller',
        localField: 'seller',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'seller_info',
      },
    },
  ]).exec();
```

all `seller_info` fields (ex: `aggregateOrdersWithSellerInfo[0].seller_info`) return an empty array:

```js
> (0) []
```

But I would expect it to return the seller associated with the `seller` field on each `Order` such as:

```js
// Seller doc
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62aa38d68e006f3006efe520"),
    firstName: 'Nikki',
    __v: 0
 }
```

Here's an example of the Order doc

```js
 {
    _id: ObjectId("62aa38d68e006f3006efe522"),
    seller: ObjectId("62aa38d68e006f3006efe520"),
    item: 'Mango Body Butter',
    __v: 0
  }
```

**How to get the associated seller document using aggregation?**

### Full Code

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connect = async (dsn) =>
  mongoose.connect(dsn, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

// Order Schema

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  seller: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Seller' },
  item: { type: String },
});

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);

// Seller Schema
const sellerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
});

const Seller = mongoose.model('Seller', sellerSchema);

// Seeder
const seedLocalDatabase = async () => {
  await connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fakewishtender');
  await Seller.deleteMany({});

  const sellers = [
    {
      firstName: 'Nikki',
    },
    {
      firstName: 'Alice',
    },
  ];

  const sellersInsertedRes = await Seller.insertMany(sellers);

  await Order.deleteMany({});
  const orders = [
    {
      seller: sellersInsertedRes.find((seller) => seller.firstName === 'Nikki')._id,
      item: 'Mango Body Butter',
    },
    {
      seller: sellersInsertedRes.find((seller) => seller.firstName === 'Alice')._id,
      item: 'Vintage Jacket',
    },
  ];

  await Order.insertMany(orders);
};

// Aggregation
(async () => {
  await seedLocalDatabase();

  const aggregateOrdersWithSellerInfo = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Seller',
        localField: 'seller',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'seller_info',
      },
    },
  ]).exec();

  const allSellers = await Seller.find({});
  const allOrders = await Order.find({});

  const sellersWithOrders = allOrders.map((order) =>
    allSellers.filter((seller) => seller._id.toJSON() === order.seller.toJSON())
  );
  const sellersPopulatedWithAggregate = aggregateOrdersWithSellerInfo.map(
    (order) => order.seller_info
  );

  console.log(
    `
    
    Sellers populated with aggregation are: 
    
    ${JSON.stringify(sellersPopulatedWithAggregate)}
    
    `
  );
  console.log(
    `But I would expect sellers populated with aggregation to be: 
    
    ${JSON.stringify(sellersWithOrders)}
    
    `
  );
  mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```

Comment: An example of a document would be helpful. my guess is you put the fields in the $lookup incorrectly. If the Order collection has a field called seller referencing the _id at the Seller collection, it should be: `$lookup: {from: 'seller', localField: 'seller', foreignField: '_id', as: 'sellerInfo'}`

Comment: I corrected that but the same issue exists. I included a Seller document but I will also include an Order document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was the name of the collection.

`Seller.collection.collectionName`  holds the collection name which was `'sellers'` so **plural** and **lowercase**.

```js
  const aggregateOrdersWithSellerInfo = await Order.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'sellers',
        localField: 'seller',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'seller_info',
      },
    },
  ]).exec();
```

You can also do `from: Seller.collection.collectionName` instead of statically typing the name